# Turán's inequalities for Hermite functions

Tags: reference-request, hermite-polynomials

Given $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ let $H_{\lambda}(x)$ be the solution of the  Hermite differential equation: 
$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} H_{\lambda}(x)-x\frac{d}{dx}H_{\lambda}(x)+\lambda H_{\lambda}(x)=0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
such that $H_{\lambda}(x) = x^{\lambda}+o(x^{\lambda})$ when $x \to +\infty$.  If $\lambda=0,1,2,..$ is a positive integer then $H_{\lambda}$ is the  [probabilists' Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) of degree $\lambda$. It is known that the Hermite polynomials do satisfy [Turán's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_inequalities), i.e.,

$$
H_{\lambda}^{2}-H_{\lambda-1}H_{\lambda+1}\geq 0 \quad  \text{for}\quad \lambda \in \mathbb{N} \quad \text{and} \quad x \in \mathbb{R}\quad (*)
$$

I suspect that (*) still holds  for all  $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Does anybody know any references about this fact? 
I believe this should be something known.

**UPDATE**

The statement is true when $x \geq L_{\lambda}$ where $L_{\lambda}$ denotes the leftmost zero of $H_{\lambda}$. 
And it follows in the same way as in http://repository.ias.ac.in/75392/1/75392.pdf
page 392. 
The same recurrence relations hold and  power growth at infinity makes the argument to work.

Question is closed!